how to model concrete balconies with xnec2c
We live on the 4th (top) floor in a suburb of Oslo.  The building is concrete, and there are two balconies.  I would like to model both balconies and try to optimize some HF antennas for various bands.
One balcony is like a shallow box 7 meters long and a couple of meters high, facing a forested ridge: there's a concrete floor, ceiling, and walls on two sides.  The back wall is wood (so maybe we can consider the apartment behind the wood wall to absorb RF only somewhat, and not reflect much?)  I'm thinking it might be sensible to make a trapped v-shaped dipole, going from the wooden railing up somewhere near the ceiling.  (So then maximum current is near the railing, maximum voltage is near the ceiling.)  On the other hand, this antenna should maybe be NVIS, because of the forested ridge being in the way.  I suspect concrete may act somewhat like a ground plane.  Should I model the concrete surfaces as GW with GM to expand the wires into surfaces?  Or as patches?  (What kind?  The multi-card patch forms seem confusing, easy to get wrong and make the model fail.)  Or should they somehow be turned into ground planes rather than wires?  Where should ground be modeled: at the floor level, or at the actual ground level farther below?  Here's what I have so far, which looks like it might be useful on the 15m band, and sends the signal outwards away from the balcony, but the swr is too high on its own:
CM --- NEC2 Input File created or edited by xnec2c 4.4.16 ---
CE --- End Comments ---
GW     2    15   0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  3.00000E+00  5.00000E-01  1.50000E+00  1.50000E-02
GW    10    15  -3.50000E+00  0.00000E+00 -1.00000E+00  3.50000E+00  0.00000E+00 -1.00000E+00  5.00000E-03
GW    11    15  -3.50000E+00  0.00000E+00  1.70000E+00  3.50000E+00  0.00000E+00  1.70000E+00  5.00000E-03
GW    12    15   3.50000E+00  0.00000E+00 -1.00000E+00  3.50000E+00  0.00000E+00  1.70000E+00  5.00000E-03
GW    13    15  -3.50000E+00  0.00000E+00 -1.00000E+00 -3.50000E+00  0.00000E+00  1.70000E+00  5.00000E-03
GM     0    20   0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  1.00000E-01  0.00000E+00  1.00000E+01
GW     1    15   0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00 -3.00000E+00  5.00000E-01  1.50000E+00  5.00000E-03
GE     0     0   0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00
EX     0     1     1      0  1.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00
FR     0    11     0      0  1.40000E+01  1.00000E+00  2.40000E+01  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00
NH     0     0     0      0  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00
NE     0    10     1     10 -1.35000E+00  0.00000E+00 -1.35000E+00  3.00000E-01  0.00000E+00  3.00000E-01
RP     0    19    37   1000  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  1.00000E+01  1.00000E+01  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00
EN     0     0     0      0  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00

The other balcony faces in a much better direction (south, towards the rest of Europe, with the land sloping gently downwards to the fjord a few kilometers away), has a nice view (not so many trees in the way), and is on the wrong end of the apartment from where I usually sit; so antennas need to be temporary.  The floor is bigger than the ceiling, and there's a concrete planter rather than a wooden railing, and a (usually folded) roll-out cloth awning with a couple of long metal poles that I need to keep the antennas away from as much as possible.  So I think the antenna here can be a straighter dipole, at an angle out away from the awning.  (Should the awning's metal parts be modeled as wires too?)  This balcony is only 6 meters long: the extra meter is taken up by a tiny wooden shed on one end, where I can put my radio temporarily and operate it either sitting there, or remotely; so I've found that a tunable QRPguys EFHW with a very-droopy length of wire works well physically, and I can get on 20m even in this 6 meter space; but if I go over 7 watts or so on 20 meters, it can cause my wifi router indoors to reset.  So I need to get rid of the EMI, and having a proper ground line is not an option.  I'm hoping that switching to a balanced dipole will generate less EMI, despite the hassle with needing to feed it from the center.  I don't mind staying QRP for now, if that's the only option.  I think if I use a pair or two of traps for higher bands, it will shorten the length to the extent that I can have the full length resonant on the 20m band.  But it would be nice to get on some of the lower bands somehow too.  Something like a "shorty forty" but even shorter, and also with traps...  So I need to figure out how to model the loading coils and traps too.  Should it be possible?

As soon as you need to start of material as volume, NEC and descendants are simply the wrong tools – they aren't able to calculate any volume properties, and that's exactly what you're asking here for. (the core concept of them is that you reduce the problem to 1D) None of your approximations (ground plane, patch…) would be justifiable without first simulating the "real geometry" with a proper antenna / EM simulator, and then coming to the conclusion that they are equivalent. I'd have very strong doubts that to a 15 MHz emission, a concrete wall looks like any of the things you propose.

Especially because the walls are in reactive near field – can't just act as if they are far away from the antenna and just "reflect some, let some through": so, a simulation based on that would not actually give you any additional insight, because the premise is wrong. Note that I won't advertise taking the time to learn how to use a "proper" EM simulator instead of xNEC here: you really can't reasonably get enough information on your building material properties, your neighbor's flats, electrical installation … to really inform a simulation that would give you a confident ability to predict…

the real world behaviour. Too many unknowns makes a simulation moot! It's just that xNEC2c simply is incapable of doing that simulation, even for the things you do see. But: you can of course at least model the things closest to your antenna, as they do tend to have the biggest influence. You'd build your antenna geometry, and the surrounding materials, in the format one of the established EM simulators can deal with; that'd be CST Studio (there's a free "Learning Edition") or FHSS, or, very very much behind, OpenEMS (still incredible software, but usability-wise and speed-wise and feature-

wise, just 4 decades behind). You'd be able to get a radiation pattern, reflection coefficient for the feedline, local field strengths, all that over as many frequencies as you like. Learning to use these tools usually takes a while.

@MarcusMüller I would also worry about the building having any steel structure, wiring, HVAC piping (e.g., condenser loop), etc.,, so that when combined, it has a much stronger impact than just a slab of lossy dielectric. One best way to deal with such an environment is to use antenna designs that naturally radiate less in that direction, but that is not easy to do in HF.

@RyujiAB1WX the problem is that "antenna design" assumes you're not putting some steel-reinforced "dielectric" (really problematic term for concrete!) into the antenna at arbitrary positions; the "doesn't radiate much in that direction" is an emergent far-field property, but for a 20m wavelength on a 7m balcony, we're completely in near-field, so that thinking really doesn't even begin to apply.

@MarcusMüller It's a matter of degree, not black-and-white. If you place an object that causes field perturbation in the direction of strong radiation vs that of weak radiation, the latter is less affected overall, even in the reactive field, unless it is super close. In real life, we experience when the antenna-induced fields interact with the placement of the feedline, common-mode choke, etc. Moving those things a bit, all within the near field, can make a sizable difference. Well, this is a bit more complicated than my previous comment... oh well.

@MarcusMüller I apparently wrote "One best way" in my earlier comment, which probably was changed by Grammarly and I failed to review or override. Please strike out "best." It is just one way.

I skipped that word, anyways :) @RyujiAB1WX It doesn't change anything: "Direction the antenna doesn't radiate as much" is an emergent property of an antenna that's not interacting with reinforced concrete and power wires etc in its reactive near field. Any conclusions drawn from the far-field radiation pattern on where it's OK to put stuff next to an antenna is fallible. You really need to look at the local field, not at the far-field approximation


how to model concrete balconies with xnec2c

not at all. NEC (and all things built atop of that 1970s program) is for wire antennas and very rudimentary boundary conditions only. (This is software that was literally written for computers of 50 years ago – that was a time with very different trade-offs of what you could not computationally do and which simplifcations you needed to make)
Numerics nerds: It's methods-of-moments solver requires reduction to 1D of the differential equations involving actual currents. That's why wire antennas work well.
Alternatives? a full 3D EM simulator would be what you use here. In theory, the free (and open) OpenEMS can do that – it just has a relatively steep learning curve, and might expect you to have some relatively intimate knowledge of EM theory to get anywhere with it. Possibilities to adjust simulation geometry and parametrics, materials and meshing in a GUI are absent.
On the more professionally typical end of things, Ansys/HFSS and CST Studio are the usual go-to software products. The latter has a free learning edition. Maybe that's what you want to use! It will mean some investment of time, though.

For HF, for an apartment block (not a huge penthouse) I would say the details of the balcony don't matter much. The concrete will have some reinforcing in it.
For a start I would say model the building as a box, like this:


Basically you need to half-close your eyes and only look at things that are bigger than a few metres. If you're on the top floor with sky above you, that's very different to a fully enclosed balcony. But the building is still just a box, the balcony isn't a big enough hole to matter.
I don't recommend patches in NEC2.

If you have EMC problems then try to prevent any RF currents from flowing in your house. A monopole-type antenna, grounded to the balcony, is one option.
If you're using an EFHW (which I like and recommend) then be sure to ground the counterpoise side of it to anything large, so that the current doesn't flow back to your radio. Ground the coax too, when it reaches the large metal object - no point in having a counterpoise and then taking your coax directly to the antenna. Also use RF chokes on the coax, even just a 10-turn coil at the feedpoint, and another one about a quarter wave closer to the radio. A dipole fed with a balun might work but - it will be parallel to the building and so it won't behave very well, also - it will radiate directly back into the building.
If your modem is picking the signal up directly from the air, not from any coax or computer/radio/power/network connection, then you probably need to start adding ferrites to its LAN, phone? and power cables.
